# При добавлении png файла, съезжает блок с текстом

Tags: html, css

[image: Сама проблема]Есть такая проблема, при добавлении png файла, съезжает блок с текстом. И еще иконку busket не могу поставить на уровне с меню.

```css
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 218px;
  height: 78px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.menu_text {
  margin-left: 440px;
  padding-top: 75px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.menu_text2 {
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.menu_text3 {
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.menu_text4 {
  margin-left: 60px;
}


/* contacts */

.phone {
  margin-left: 70px;
  width: 18px;
}

.busket {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 1200px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.number {
  color: #000000;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 21px;
  padding-top: 70px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.title1 {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 56px;
  width: 450px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.about_mag {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 410px;
  margin-left: 150px;
}

.animal {
  width: 800px;
  margin-left: 550px;
}

.batton_frends {
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  border: none;
  background: linear-gradient(128.41deg, #FF4E36 22.49%, #FF1F00 70.19%);
}

.batton_frends:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 34px rgba(255, 82, 58, 0.8);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.see_freinds {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 21px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.see_freinds:hover {
  text-decoration-line: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="backgraund_site">
  <!-- menu -->
  <div class="backgraund_head">
    <img src="icon_jpg/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
    <div class="menu_text">
      <span class="menu_text1">Главная</span>
      <span class="menu_text2">Друзья</span>
      <span class="menu_text3">О сервисе</span>
      <span class="menu_text4">Контакты</span>
      <img src="icon_jpg/Phone.png" alt="Phone" class="phone">
      <span><a href="tel:0689693487"  class="number">068 969 34 87</a></span>
    </div>
    <img src="icon_jpg/animal.png" alt="animal" class="animal">
    <div>
      <img src="icon_jpg/busket.png" alt="busket" class="busket">
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3 class="title1">Твой новый друг с доставкой на дом</h3>
      <p class="about_mag">Онлайн магазин домашних животных - удобное решение, когда лень выходить их дома</p>
      <button class="batton_frends"> <span class="see_freinds">Посмотреть друзей</span> </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста скрин макета

Comment: Добавил, там видно в чем суть проблемы.

Comment: у animal надо задать position: absolute, у родителя busket тоже самое

Comment: их надо абсолютно позиционировать

Comment: Спасибо, вроде поставило их на место, только теперь их нужно поднять чуть выше, а картинки не подымаются, пробовал  margin-top и padding-top...

Comment: Если нужно задать отступ для абсолютного дива, то не нужно добавлять margin/padding. Просто, `top: 30px;`

Comment: Оооо спасибо, помогло, а можешь подсказать как сделать, что бы весь контент сайта был по центру страницы, а то у меня как то все с левой стороны

Comment: @ED Root для этого есть margin: 0 auto, вам надо задать это свойство своему контейнеру

Comment: спасибо, помогло)) ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй так. Картинку животных используй как фон для backgraund_head. basket я перенес в навигационную панель. Твой html код тут не работает у меня нет картинок поэтому я не уверен. class один можно использоватьт для нескольких элементов, а id для одного.

```css
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 218px;
  height: 78px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.menu_text {
  margin-left: 440px;
  padding-top: 75px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.menu_text2 {
  margin-left: 60px;
}

/* contacts */

.phone {
  margin-left: 70px;
  width: 18px;
}

.busket {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 70px;
}

.number {
  color: #000000;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 21px;
  padding-top: 70px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.title1 {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 56px;
  width: 450px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.about_mag {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 410px;
  margin-left: 150px;
}

.backgraund_head {
  background-image: url(icon_jpg/animal.png);
}

.batton_frends {
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  border: none;
  background: linear-gradient(128.41deg, #FF4E36 22.49%, #FF1F00 70.19%);
}

.batton_frends:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 34px rgba(255, 82, 58, 0.8);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.see_freinds {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 21px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.see_freinds:hover {
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="backgraund_site">
  <!-- menu -->
  <div class="backgraund_head">
    <img src="icon_jpg/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
    <div class="menu_text">
      <span class="menu_text1">Главная</span>
      <span class="menu_text2">Друзья</span>
      <span class="menu_text2">О сервисе</span>
      <span class="menu_text2">Контакты</span>
      <img src="icon_jpg/Phone.png" alt="Phone" class="phone">
      <span><a href="tel:0689693487"  class="number">068 969 34 87</a></span>
      <img src="icon_jpg/busket.png" alt="busket" class="busket">
    </div> 
    <div>
      <h3 class="title1">Твой новый друг с доставкой на дом</h3>
      <p class="about_mag">Онлайн магазин домашних животных - удобное решение, когда лень выходить их дома</p>
      <button class="batton_frends"> <span class="see_freinds">Посмотреть друзей</span> </button>
    </div>
```